# Where is Scala's += defined in the context of Int?

Tags: scala, operators

Just starting out with Scala
`var c = 0`
`c += 1` works
`c.+=` gives me `error: value += is not a member of Int`

Where is the `+=` defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Section 6.12.4 *Assignment Operators* of the Scala Language Specification (SLS)](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators) explains how such compound assignment operators are desugared:

```
l ω= r
```

(where `ω` is any sequence of operator characters other than `<`, `>`, `!` and doesn't start with `=`) gets desugared to

```
l.ω=(r)
```

**IFF** `l` has a member named `ω=` or is implicitly convertible to an object that has a member named `ω=`.

Otherwise, it gets desugared to

```
l = l.ω(r)
```

(except `l` is guaranteed to be only evaluated once), if that typechecks.

Or, to put it more simply: the compiler will first try `l.ω=(r)` and if that doesn't work, it will try `l = l.ω(r)`.

This allows something like `+=` to work like it does in other languages but still be overridden to do something different.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the code you've described does work.

```
scala> var c = 4
c: Int = 4

scala> c.+=(2)  // no output because assignment is not an expression

scala> c
res1: Int = 6
```

I suspect (but can't say for sure) that it can't be found in the library because the compiler de-surgars (rewrites) it to `c = c.+(1)`, which *is* in the library.

Comment: Ah, so c.+= is actually sugar rather than a real function? (don't give it a parameter).

Comment: I believe so.  When I write `c.` in an IntelliJ worksheet I'm offered a menu of possible completions, but `+=` is not among them.

Comment: I believe the `+=` from implicit resolution.

Comment: @marios, I'm not finding it.  I tried `scalac -Xlog-implicit-conversions test.scala` and got no indication of an implicit conversion taking place.

Comment: @jwvh you are right. It seems that scala in injecting a synthetic method at runtime to cover this case. The best reason I can see for doing that is to avoid boxing altogether.  Maybe

Comment: This important little section: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators